# What are the usual types of loss sources in an Inverter?

Tags: inverter, electrical

What are the usual loss sources in an common Inverter?

Thanks,
Devin.

Comment: You need a full cycle of lectures in one post online? Good luck

Comment: Hello Greogory, no an overview would do the trick.

Comment: About 20% I would say.

Comment: A good 3-phase inverter rated above 5 kW or so with 400 to 700 volts output could have as little as 2% to 4% losses. "Any common inverter" could have quite a bit higher losses, but I think 20% would apply only to the smallest not so good products. If you want an overview of loss sources, revise the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest losses in an inverter are probably the forward drop losses in the switching semiconductors.

- With inductive loads there are forward drop losses in the antiparallel diodes.
- Switching losses in the semiconductors could be just as much or more  depending on PWM switching frequency.
- There are also ESR losses in filter capacitors for the DC bus. 
  The   reactive component of inductive loads represents the majority of   capacitor ripple current for 3-phase inverters with inductive loads.
- If there are DC bus chokes or line reactors, the copper and iron losses in those can be significant.
- Losses in snubber circuits is another item.
- All of the power for the control and driver circuits would be considered to be a loss.
- Any power for forced cooling fans is a loss.

I think those are the

major losses.